# Unable to call a REST Jersey resource through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jersey

I am trying to use Jersey to create RESTful resource. What I want is that clicking on a link, BookResource should be accessed and display the list of books which are in the database. Right now all I want is the function in JavaScript to throw an alert that it did make the ajax call. However, it goes in request.fail loop and doesn't do anything.

```
BookResource.java


import com.helper.BooksHelper;
import com.servlets.Book;

@Path("/books")
public class BookResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/allBooks")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllBooks() {

        BooksHelper bookHelper = new BooksHelper();
        ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks = bookHelper.getListOfBooks();

        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK);
        responseBuilder.entity(listOfBooks);

        Response response = responseBuilder.build();
        return response;    
    }
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Library Management System</h2>
    <h3>Welcome, ${username}</h3>

    <p>List of books in library  <a href="" onclick="libBooks();">Click Here</a></p>

    <div id="bookList"></div>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!
</body>
</html>
```

list.js

```
function libBooks(){

    alert("Inside js");
    //The above alert is displayed
    var requestData = {
            "dataType":  "json",
            "type":  "GET",
            "url":  "http://localhost:8080/library/webapi/books/allBooks"
    };

    var request = $.ajax(requestData);
    alert("Ajax call made");
    //The above alert is displayed

    request.success(function(data) {

        alert("Inside done function");
        //The above alert is not displayed

        var dataReceived =data.listOfBooks;
        var numOfItems = dataReceived.length;
        alert(numOfItems);

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, status, errorMessage) {
        if((errorMessage = $.trim(errorMessage)) === "") {
            alert("An unspecified error occurred.  Check the server error log for details.");
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred:  " + errorMessage);
            //The above alert is displayed
        }
    });
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.-------(hidden).library</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I want an alert on index.jsp itself which confirms that ajax call successful. The url that I start application is with http://localhost:8080/library/login.jsp
and then on successful login url changes to http://localhost:8080/library/login, which is where I have a link,

List of books in library  Click Here

, but nothing happens on clicking it except for alert "Inside js" and "Ajax call made". I get an error in console developer tools that "http://localhost:8080/library/webapi/books/allBooks" could not be found. What am I doing wrong. I followed numerous examples online and this is how they are doing it. Is the url incorrect? Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

[image: Maven Directory Structure]

Comment: Have you tried opening the service url in a browser? It seems to me that you are missing some part of the address, but I can't tell what's the missing part from the info that you posted. The only hint is that maybe "library" is not the name of the web application hosting the services. Alternatively you can try specifying "application/json" instead of "json" in the request parameters.

Comment: Also set content type  contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: @francescoforesti I tried opening it directly in the browser. A plain page is obtained with the alert that states error from the failure loop of Ajax call. I changed json to application/json as well but no change. I am attaching screenshot of my directory structure. Please do let me know if there is any code you would like to see.

Comment: @AllahbakshAsadullah I set contentType: 'application/json' but it didn't make any affect. Please suggest something. I have been stuck on this for two days now. Thank You.

Comment: Is there anyway I can debug the resource. Meaning in terms of headers being sent and received?

Comment: Does it have something to do with as to where Jersey can find whatever it needs to make a call to a resource. I was searching online and it says something about init param and init param value in web.xml file. Something wrong there?

Comment: I think error might be in my href tag in jsp. I think I need to specify as to where it should go on clicking that link. I am not sure what it should be. I have tried a few combinations but nothing worked.

Comment: You can try debugging your calls with the developer console of Chrome (or any other serious browser).

Comment: @francescoforesti I have been using it. It hasn't been of much help. Will it be feasible to achieve my objective without using JavaScript?

Comment: You could do it with some other language, but why should you? Again, if you paste [http://localhost:8080/library/webapi/books/allBooks](http://localhost:8080/library/webapi/books/allBooks) in your browser, doest it say 404 (not found)? If that's the case, the problem lies in the server side, so your javascript is not the culprit. Instead, if the service is resolved and your browser shows the books you expect, then the problem is with javascript. You could try using $.get(requestData)` instead of $.ajax(requestData)`.

Comment: @francescoforesti Yes I do get 404 not found. I tried $.get but still the same thing.

Comment: Then the problem is not javascript. It is that the service is on another url. Find out what the url of the service is, and put that url in the javascript request.

Comment: @francescoforesti Nothing is working and I am sick and tired of this use case.